# Check if one input doesn't have a value in a group of other input in an array JQUERY

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, input

I was wondering if it was possible to check in an array if one of the input that compose this array is without a value, without checking them one by one.

for example if you have a form with multiple input and you forgot to fill one of the input it will tell you if you click on the 'send' button that one input is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If your are using jQuery, you can loop on input with each() and check if they are empty or not